# localized output for `date` command

Tags: macos, bash, date, localization

How can I localize output of date command in MacOSX bash environment?
for example, I want to localize following in ru_RU locale:

```
$ date +"%d %B %Y"
07 April 2011
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing "date" to use a locale other than the machine default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896509/forcing-date-to-use-a-locale-other-than-the-machine-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
LC_ALL=ru_RU date +"%d %B %Y"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have ru_RU installed, so I show it with de/us:

```
env LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 date +"%d %B %Y" -d +2months
>  07 June 2011
env LC_ALL=de_DE.utf8 date +"%d %B %Y" -d +2months
>  07 Juni 2011
```