# Forcing "date" to use a locale other than the machine default

Tags: bash, unix, date

Is there a way to force the *nix command "date" to output in a specific format independent of the local? For example, if I call "date -u" today, on a US machine I get:

```
Mon Oct 15 13:15:29 UTC 2012
```

but on a German machine I get:

```
Mo 15. Okt 13:15:31 UTC 2012
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Sure, you can always specify the format yourself:

```
date +%a, %b %d
```

or you can use a temporary environmental variable:

```
:~$ LC_ALL=de_DE.utf8 date
Mo 15. Okt 15:34:11 CEST 2012
:~$ date
Mon Oct 15 15:33:24 CEST 2012
```

As you see, only the first command is run with the German locale.

Comment: additionally you can use `locale -a` to list the installed locales which will work for the `LC_ALL` variable

Comment: I can't make it work the other way around. For example `LC_ALL=it_IT.utf8 date -d'1 gennaio 2017' +%Y%m%d` says: `date: invalid date ‘1 gennaio 2017’`

Comment: "In the current implementation, only English is supported for words and abbreviations like ‘AM’, ‘DST’, ‘EST’, ‘first’, ‘January’, ‘Sunday’, ‘tomorrow’, and ‘year’." (info page for date)

Comment: The correct variable is **LC_TIME**, that is `LC_TIME=de_DE.utf8 date`. It might not matter for the single command, but since the page is the first search result for a general query, it's probably worth mentioning.

Comment: In my shell I had to put `date`'s parameters in a quote like this: `date +"%a, %b %d"`

Comment: @Hi-Angel You are correct that LC_TIME affects how the date is printed but LC_ALL has a higher priority. I.e. if **LC_ALL** is set then LC_TIME is ignored. Therefore setting just LC_TIME does not guarantee a correct language.

Comment: @bedrorom right, that does not mean though that setting `LC_ALL` instead of `LC_TIME` just to change time format is the correct solution. Rather it means that you might want to check that `LC_ALL` is not set. It is often the case that one wants to get a 24h time format instead of the AM/PM one, but they do not want to change the language *(which is gonna happen if you set `LC_ALL`)*.

Comment: Actually, I'm sorry, but I figured I'll give this answer a downvote until it is edited. Because `LC_ALL` should only really be used for debugging purposes, exactly because you lose the more fine-grained control over the rest of `LC_*` variables. As a result of this answer people may set `LC_ALL` in the environment, and later then stumble upon problems similar to what @bedrorom mentioned. Nothing good in that.

Comment: nice, however, `LC_ALL=es_ES.utf8; date --utc --date "30 dic 2023 16:35:20 GMT-8" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"` does not work as expected.

Answer (score 16):

You can modify the environment `date` runs in. I don't know if this is the best way (the variables used in locale handling are numerous), but the following works:

```
$ LANG=de_DE date
Mo 15 Okt 2012 09:34:12 EDT
```

(January beat me to this answer by a minute or so, but I'll leave my answer up in the hopes that some will clarify which variable (`LC_ALL`, `LANG`, other) is most "appropriate".)

Comment: Your answer is more "appropriate", examples from [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html): `LANG=da_DK.iso_8859-1 date`, `LANG=De_DE.88591 date`.

Comment: Definitions from [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html): `Lang` can be used by applications to determine the language to use for error messages and instructions, collating sequences, **date formats**, and so on. `LC_ALL` determine the values for all locale categories and has precedence over any of the other environment variables.

Answer (score 8):

`LC_TIME` is enough, you can use this.

```
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"  date
```

Answer (score 6):

## Install the `language-pack-xx`

First, make sure that the language package of the target locale is installed. On Debian-derived GNU/Linux distributions, Dutch language support is installed as follows:

```
$ sudo apt install language-pack-nl
```

This command will automatically also install `language-pack-nl-base`.
Here is what I get by specifying `LC_TIME`. This is more specific than using `LC_ALL`. (Specifying `LANG` does not work on Xubuntu LTS.)

```
$ date '+%A %e %B %Y'
Friday 16 October 2015

$ LC_TIME='nl_BE.UTF-8' date '+%A %e %B %Y'
vrijdag 16 oktober 2015
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me :-(

LC_TIME='de_DE.UTF-8' date  '+%A %e %B %Y'

gives 

Saturday  3 December 2022

Comment: @framp: did you do install `language-pack-de` before trying? and is `de_DE.utf8` included in the output of `locale -a` ?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the following? (which I got from the date manual pages)

```
# date -u +"%a %b %d %T %Z %Y"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a step in the right direction, but I want the day and month names (which are in German on a German machine) to switch to English as well.

Answer (score 2):

UTC:

```
date -u -R
```

Local:

```
date -R
```

Answer (score 1):

First, uncomment your desired locale(s) lines in `/etc/locale.gen` then run `locale-gen` (both as root).
Make sure your terminal supports the required encoding so the characters will get shown.

You can then specify a "temporary" locale for the run-time of one command like this:

```
LC_ALL="de_DE.UTF-8" date
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this knowledge to write date and time information used in scripts for the benefit of speakers of other languages, for example:

```
    LC_TIME="es_PR.utf8" date '+El programa concluyó el %A, %e de %B de %Y, a las %H horas, %M minutos'
```